# Optparse callback not consuming argument

Tags: python, optparse

I'm trying to get to know `optparse` a bit better, but I'm struggling to understand why the following code behaves the way it does. Am I doing something stupid?

```
import optparse

def store_test(option, opt_str, value, parser, args=None, kwargs=None):
    print 'opt_str:', opt_str
    print 'value:', value

op = optparse.OptionParser()
op.add_option('-t', '--test', action='callback', callback=store_test, default='test', 
    dest='test', help='test!')

(opts, args) = op.parse_args(['test.py', '-t', 'foo'])

print
print 'opts:'
print opts
print 'args:'
print args
```

**Output:**

```
opt_str: -t
value: None

opts:
{'test': 'test'}
args:
['foo']
```

Why is `'foo'` not being passed to `store_test()` and instead being interpreted as an extra argument? Is there something wrong with `op.parse_args(['-t', 'foo'])`?

### ↓

### http://codepad.org/vq3cvE13

**Edit:**

Here's the example from the docs:

```
def store_value(option, opt_str, value, parser):
    setattr(parser.values, option.dest, value)
[...]
parser.add_option("--foo",
                  action="callback", callback=store_value,
                  type="int", nargs=3, dest="foo")
```

Comment: Perhaps off-topic, but you should definitely give `argparse` a try : http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Comment: You don't actually want to pass in the filename - http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html says "by default [parse_args()] uses `sys.argv[1:]`".

Comment: If you're overriding the default by giving it an argument then that's not relevant though is it? Here's the relevant code from `optparse.py`: `if args is None:
            return sys.argv[1:]
        else:
            return args[:]`

Comment: It'll still work, but just ignore the filename since it's not an option.

Comment: Seconding @Evpok, chances are, you shouldn't be wasting your time learning `optparse`, which is [deprecated](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#optparse-option-callbacks) as of python 2.7. Learn [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) instead.

Comment: It will not ignore the filename if you are supplying a list of arguments to `parse_args()`. @senderle - not keen on adding another dependency to a simple script though..

Comment: @Acorn, not sure what you mean. Assuming you're using python 2.7+, `argparse` is in the standard library -- is that really a "dependency"? Also, you wouldn't be adding a dependency, you'd be exchanging one "dependency" on a standard module for another. Of course if you're using an older version of python, that's another matter. In any case, it was just a suggestion :)

Comment: @senderle - I'm using 2.6. I'll definitely be taking a look into `argparse` soon though, thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a "type" <strike>or "nargs"</strike> option attribute:

```
op.add_option('-t', '--test', action='callback', callback=store_test, default='test',
    dest='test', help='test!', type='str')
```

This option will cause it to consume the next argument.

Reference:
http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#optparse-option-callbacks

> **type**
>      has its usual meaning: as with the "store" or "append" actions, it instructs optparse 
>   to consume one argument and convert it to type. Rather than storing the converted 
>   value(s) anywhere, though, optparse passes it to your callback function.
>
> **nargs**
>      also has its usual meaning: if it is supplied and > 1, optparse will consume nargs 
>   arguments, each of which must be convertible to type. It then passes a tuple of converted 
>   values to your callback.

This seems to be the relevant code from `optparse.py`:

```
def takes_value(self):
    return self.type is not None

def _process_short_opts(self, rargs, values):
    [...]
        if option.takes_value():
            # Any characters left in arg?  Pretend they're the
            # next arg, and stop consuming characters of arg.
            if i < len(arg):
                rargs.insert(0, arg[i:])
                stop = True

            nargs = option.nargs
            if len(rargs) < nargs:
                if nargs == 1:
                    self.error(_("%s option requires an argument") % opt)
                else:
                    self.error(_("%s option requires %d arguments")
                               % (opt, nargs))
            elif nargs == 1:
                value = rargs.pop(0)
            else:
                value = tuple(rargs[0:nargs])
                del rargs[0:nargs]

        else:                       # option doesn't take a value
            value = None

        option.process(opt, value, values, self)
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out that it doesn't work without the `str` option. Odd. The `nargs` option is definitely not needed as the default number of `args` to consume is `1`.

Comment: After testing, `type` is the key, not `nargs`. If you specify `nargs=1`, but no `type` it still doesn't work.

Comment: This is kind of a nasty gotcha, IMHO.  I can see that, if I had explicitly said "type=None", it might imply, "hey, there should be No Argument Here."  But I can't justify *implicitly* implying that the callback should have 0-arity